# Getting json using http web request using get

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, get, httpwebrequest, http-get

i'm trying to get a response from an httpwebrequest using get method and content type json..
but i'm getting `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type`

here is my code:

```
Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
Dim reqBytes As Byte() = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPost)
objRequest.Method = "GET"
objRequest.Timeout = "15000"
objRequest.ContentLength = reqBytes.Length
objRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8" 

Try
   myWriter = objRequest.GetRequestStream()
   myWriter.Write(reqBytes, 0, reqBytes.Length)

Catch e As Exception
   writetotext(e.toString)
End Try
```

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP GET cannot have a message body. Data gets typically passed through the URI path and query string and not through message body for GET requests. For POST, PUT, etc, you should be able to do what you are trying to do in the code above.

Comment: ok so i removed this `objRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8" ` but i need to get the response of the request as json is there anything i have to add?

Comment: Try `objRequest.Accept="application\json"`. But the main problem is you cannot write into the request stream. GET cannot have a message body. The payload you have in the form of `strPost` can be either posted using "POST" method or passed in, in the form of query string.